# How do I pop up a download prompt?

Tags: php

I am using this to put the contents to a file

```
file_put_contents('abc.txt', $text);
```

I need to have a pop up for the user after this to save/download the file
how would I do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will give the user a download prompt:

```
<?php                                                                
header('Content-type: text/plain');                             

// What file will be named after downloading                                  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.txt"');

// File to download                                
readfile('abc.txt');                                            
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The manual on [`fpassthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) has a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Content-Disposition header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.txt"');
readfile('abc.txt');
```

Be sure to send the appropriate Content-Type header as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the right headers:

```
header("Content-disposition: Atachment");
```